# npm winston set log level for basic logging instance

Tags: node.js, winston

Setting winston log level to 'debug' in 'easy mode' was not well documented so I've shown an example below (and will submit a PR soon).

the answer is `winston.level = 'debug'`

I want to use the winston logging package in a node script and not bother with any config, just be able to call `winston.debug`, `winston.info`, `winston.error` and then pass in the log level as a command line param. The docs for 'easy mode' did not include how to set log level so I've shown it below.

The code:

```
var winston = require('winston');

winston.transports.Console.level = "debug";

winston.log("error", "error test 1");
winston.log("info", "info test 1");
winston.log("debug", "debug test 1");

winston.level = "debug";

winston.log("error", "error test 2");
winston.log("info", "info test 2");
winston.log("debug", "debug test 2");
```

Will output:

```
error: error test 1
info: info test 1
error: error test 2
info: info test 2
debug: debug test 2
```

Hope this helps

Comment: PR: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/pull/554

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is `winston.level = 'debug'`